# Gearman with mysql support

Tags: mysql, node.js, gearman

I have complied gearman 1.1.18 on ubuntu 16 .
I am using gearman with node library

```
const gearman = require('gearman');

let client = gearman("localhost", 4730, { timeout: 10000 });  // timeout in milliseconds. 


// handle finished jobs
client.on('WORK_COMPLETE', function (job) {
   console.log('job completed, result:', job.payload.toString());
   client.close();
});


// connect to the gearman server
client.connect(function () {

   client.submitJob('upper', 'Hello, World!', { background: true, 'priority': 'normal' });

});
```

Issue is I can connect to mysql and has table also but when I submit background job with gearman table is not getting populated .

Any suggestions ?

Comment: your post contains only client side implementation and only a sentence regarding the issue. If you really looking for help, you have to add description of your setup and worker implementation.

Comment: @palik ... Lets have one to one chat

Comment: you have to invite me because I never used stackoverflow chat before ;-/

Comment: Can you show the command you are using to run the Gearman server?  By default, Gearman does not use a database but runs in memory.  You must pass in the right command line parameters to connect to a database.